# constructorless initialization and Dictionaries

Tags: c#-3.0

Using C# 3.0, we can initialize objects without their constructors for syntactical reasons. Such as ..

```
ClassName c = new ClassName = 
{
  Property1 = "Value"
}
```

I was wondering how this works with Dictionaries and adding the items to them. Any ideas?

```
class Foo
{
 public Dictionary<string,int> DictionaryObject { get; set; }
}

Foo f = new Foo =
{
 // ??? 
}
```

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: ReSharper can do that automatically for you. When you write your code without constructor initialization it will propose to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Foo
{
    public Dictionary<string,int> DictionaryObject { get; set; }
}

Foo f = new Foo =
{
    DictionaryObject = new Dictionary<string,int>
    {
        {"value1", 42},
        {"value2", 43}
    }
}
```